# sendkey code that will interrupt screen saver and not trigger help.txt in vi?

Tags: powershell, vi, sendkeys, screensaver

I have a powershell script running in the background to interrupt the screen saver. Unfortunately this has a very annoying side effect of triggering help.txt in vi when it has focus (e.g. via PuTTY).

Does anyone know of a sendkey code that will both interrupt the screen saver  and not trigger help.txt in vi?

I have tried the following with no luck:

```
sendkeys("{NUMLOCK}{NUMLOCK}")
sendkeys("^")
sendkeys("{F15}")
sendkeys("{PRTSC}")
sendkeys("{SCROLLLOCK}{SCROLLLOCK}")
```

Any other suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: I suggest looking into less brittle ways to deactivate the screen saver.

Comment: Is disabling the screensaver no option ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you have the screen saver? Why not set screen saver settings directly?

Comment: I do not have control over screen saver settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this in PuTTY by updating the session configuration under Terminal=>Keyboard

In the section marked: The Function keys and keypad
Select Xterm R6

This seems to prevent the sendkey code from triggering help text in vi

Answer (score 0):

rather than send keys why not just move the mouse pointer like below

```
param($Minutes = 60)

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Minutes; $i++) {
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
  $Pos = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position
[System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = New-Object System.Drawing.Point((($Pos.X) + 1) , $Pos.Y)
}
```

Comment: This looks promising but so far it is not working to prevent screen saver. Thanks though, I will keep trying.